# Can CUDA results be stored in an OpenGL accessible texture?

Tags: memory, opengl, cuda, textures

Can CUDA be used to generate OpenGL textures? I know it can be done by reading the CUDA results back into system memory, and then loading that into a texture... But I'd like to find a way to save this copy... Can CUDA be used to generate textures?

Comment: I don't know about CUDA, but I know OpenCL can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, CUDA has API functions to allow for OpenGL Interoperability

Use `cudaGLRegisterBufferObject(GLuint bufObj)` to register to CUDA and then use `cudaGLMapBufferObject( void ** devPtr, GLuint bufObj)` to get the device memory pointer to manipulate the buffer in your CUDA kernal.

Once done, you unmap `cudaGLUnmapBufferObject(GLuint bufObj)` and then display.

Full explanation is in the CUDA Programming Guide that you download in the CUDA Toolkit.

Answer (score 5):

Sort of. You can't write directly to textures from a kernel, but you can do a copy of the results from your kernel to the texture's mapped cudaArray without having to copy it back to system memory. Look into `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage()`, `cudaGraphicsMapResources()` and `cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray()`.

Comment: Also note that these are the new 3.0 versions. The other GL - Dx will be deprecated